# React router on Apache HTTP server with nested routes

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

I have an Apache HTTP server running in foo.org. I want to host in `foo.org/path1/my_app` a react web app that uses **react router**

```
<Router basename="/" history={history} >
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/route1" exact component={Route1Component} />
      <Route path="/:id/edit" exact component={Route2Component} /> // nested route!
      <Route component={ErrorComponent} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

I included in `foo.org/path1/my_app` a **.htaccess** file with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /    
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l    
    RewriteRule . /path1/my_app/index.html [L]   
</IfModule>
```

In my **package.json** I set the homepage attribute to match a relative path
`"homepage": "./"`

However when I test the deployed app looks like react router does not know any of routes since all routes are falled back to the 404 error component.

Comment: Can you clarify what your react-app (client-side) URLs are?

Comment: the client side URLs are the ones shown in the `<Router>` Component. so "/" & "/route1" . The visible URLs should bee "foo.org/path1/my_app/" & "foo.org/path1/my_app/route1"